# Form value is not inserted

Tags: php

I have a problem when inserting a value of a form into a variable, I put a small part of the code since it would not take up many unnecessary lines.

When I enter the data in the form if I do a var_dump of `$ _POST ['test']`, I see that if this is the data that I have set but I do not know why it is not stored in this line:

> $this->assignSubject($_POST['test'], $name);

If for example, I put in the input of the form a default value with `value =` if you save it correctly.

What could be the problem?

```
class Secretary {

    public $students = array();
    public $subjects = array();

    public function findStudent($n) {
        foreach($this->students as $d) {
            if($d->getName() == $n) return ($d);
                 }
            return false;
        }

    public function findSubject($n) {
        foreach($this->subjects as $p) {
            if($p->getName() == $n) return ($p);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function assignSubject($pName, $dName) {
        $subject = $this->findSubject($pName);
        $student = $this->findStudent($dName);
        if($subject && $student) {

            $student->subjectsAssign[] = $subject;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function checkName($name) {

        if(array_search($name, array_column($this->students, 'name')) !== false) {

            form();

            if ($_POST['action'] == "recordData") {
                    // I do not save the form data in $ _POST ['test'].
                    $this->assignSubject($_POST['test'], $name);
                }
            }
            else {
                otherForm();
            }
        }
    }
}

function form(){

    echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" >
    <label>Add the subject : </label><INPUT TYPE = "text" NAME = "test"> <br>
    <INPUT TYPE = "hidden" NAME = "action" VALUE = "recordData">
    <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" >
    </ FORM>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the this for class variables. Thays why it's not doing anything.

```
public function assignSubject($pName, $dName) {
    $subject = $this->findSubject($pName);
    $student = $this->findStudent($dName);
    if($subject && $student) {

        $this->student->subjectsAssign[] = $subject;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```